# How do i remove the extra 2 download icons in this angular code if there are 3 users

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular

So here is the html code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users">
              <td>
                <h6 class="font-medium">{{user.id}}</h6>
              </td>
              <td>
                <h6 class="font-medium">{{user.totalPrice}}</h6>
              </td>
              <td>
                <button type="button" *ngFor="let user of users" (click)="downloadJson(user.id)"<i>icon</i></button></td>
```

And here is the typescript method:

```
downloadJson(userId: String) { 

    const user = this.users.find(u => u.id === userId);
    if (user) {
      const jsonString = JSON.stringify(user, null, 2);
      const blob = new Blob([jsonString], { type: 'application/json' });

      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.download = `user_data_${userId}.json`; // Include user ID in the file name

      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    } else {
      console.error(`User with ID ${userId} not found`);
    }
```

I have tried different ways to remove them but it hasn't worked i want it to only show the download item for the correct id

Comment: If you want one download button, then why do `<button type="button" *ngFor="let user of users"`? You already have an `ngFor` above. You're making one row for each user, then in that row making one button for each user. Don't. Make one button.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem it was in `<button type="button" *ngFor="let user of users" (click)="downloadJson(user.id)"<i>icon</i></button></td>`
the problem is the `*ngFor="let user of users"`